# Split dataframe by column values Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to split a dataframe into multiple dataframes by the timestamp column. So I would provide a number of hours that this dataframe should contain and will get a set of dataframes with a specified number of hours in each of those.

The signature of the method would look like this:

```
def splitDataframes(df: DataFrame, hoursNumber: Int): Seq[DataFrame]
```

How can I achieve that?

The schema of the dataframe looks like this:

```
root
 |-- date_time: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- order_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- event_ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- event_hour: long (nullable = true)
```

Some of the input df fields:

```
event_ts, user_id
2020-12-13 08:22:00, 1
2020-12-13 08:51:00, 2
2020-12-13 09:28:00, 1
2020-12-13 10:53:00, 3
2020-12-13 11:05:00, 1
2020-12-13 12:19:00, 2
```

Some of the output df fields with hoursNumber=2:

```
df1   event_ts, user_id
      2020-12-13 08:22:00, 1
      2020-12-13 08:51:00, 2
      2020-12-13 09:28:00, 1
df2   2020-12-13 10:46:00, 3
      2020-12-13 11:05:00, 1
df3   2020-12-13 12:48:00, 2
```

Comment: why is 2020-12-13 12:19:00 in a separate dataframe? it's within 2 hours of 2020-12-13 10:53:00

Comment: Well, I counted starting from even hours like 2020-12-13 10:00:00, therefore this time does not fall into this dataframe. I will update the value so it wouldn't be confusing

Comment: I've edited my answer to do it in your way, see if it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the timestamp to unix timestamp, and then work out the id for each row using the time difference from the earliest timestamp.

**EDIT:** the solution is even simpler if you count starting time from 00:00:00.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def splitDataframes(df: DataFrame, hoursNumber: Int): Seq[DataFrame] = {

    val df2 = df.withColumn(
        "event_unix_ts",
        unix_timestamp($"event_ts")
    ).withColumn(
        "grouping",
        floor($"event_unix_ts" / (3600 * hoursNumber))
    ).drop("event_unix_ts")
    
    val df_array = df2.select("grouping").distinct().collect().map(
                   x => df2.filter($"grouping" === x(0)).drop("grouping")).toSeq
    
    return df_array

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tested that a step of a few hours is too small and I actually need to take like 4-10 days in one batch. How can this solution be configured to take a few days in one batch without simply multiplying the hours number? There is a date column that can be used for that

Comment: @Cassie use 86400 instead of 3600. a day has 86400 seconds.

Comment: Sounds like an option, thanks for the idea. Can the same floor algorithm be applied to dates or it's better to operate on hours?

Comment: @Cassie I think it can, because the input is cast to unix timestamps in this code, so presumably it should work with both dates or timestamps

Comment: I meant without re-using unix_timestamps just using dates. Can Spark functions like date_sub or date_add be used for that?

Comment: @Cassie You can't divide dates by integers - the type is not compatible. You'll need to convert the dates to an integer, i.e. unix_timestamp.

Comment: Yeah, I undestand. But I meant that instead of division subtraction of days can be defined for dates

Comment: @Cassie I see what you mean now, then yes, it should be possible to implement that, but if you don't mind could you open another question with sample data, desired output etc..? It is very different from what you have asked for in this question.